# node.js: Control from the master cluster

Tags: node.js, redis, cluster-computing

Is it possible to turn on/off redis subscribe dynamically from the master cluster? The reason I ask is that I just want one cluster subscribed at a time, but in case that cluster dies I need to get another one to subscribe.

Fundamentally, is it possible for master cluster to send messages to forked clusters just through the api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the master, you can send messages to cluster easily, you just have to save worker object which is a result of fork() call.

```
var cluster = require("cluster");
worker = cluster.fork();
worker.on("message,function(msg){
  console.log("Master says:" + msg);
});
worker.send({message:'hello'});
```

Comment: This is great! Can you improve your answer so the listener is actually set up in the worker? This woud be tremendously helpful to me